# While doing Lp estimates, is the constant C monotonically increasing with respect to the parameters it depends on?

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, sobolev-spaces, parabolic-pde, regularity

For example, consider the third boundary value problem:
\begin{align}
    &\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}-\sum_{i,j=1}^n a_{ij}(x,t) \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x_i \partial x_j} + \sum_{i=1}^n b_i(x,t) \frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i} + c(x,t) u = f(x,t), \quad (x,t) \in Q_T \\
    &\frac{\partial u}{\partial \mathbf{n}} + b(x,t) u = g(x,t), \quad x \in \partial \Omega, \ 0<t \leq T, \\
    &u(x,0)=u_0(x), \quad x \in \Omega,
\end{align}
where $Q_T=\Omega \times (0,T]$, $0<T<+\infty$, $\Omega ⊂ \mathbb{R}^n$ is open and bounded, and $\partial \Omega \in C^2$. Suppose $a_{ij} \in C(\overline{Q_T})$, $a_{ij}=a_{ji}$ $(i,j=1,\dots,n)$, and there exist positive constants $\lambda$ and $\Lambda$, s.t.
\begin{equation}
\lambda |\xi|^2 \leq \sum_{i,j=1}^n a_{ij}(x,t) \xi_i \xi_j \leq \Lambda |\xi|^2, \quad \forall (x,t) \in \overline{Q_T}, \ \xi \in \mathbb{R}^n.
\end{equation}
Suppose also that $b_i, c \in L^\infty(Q_T)$ $(i=1,\dots,n)$, $f \in L^p(Q_T)$ $(1<p<+\infty)$, $b \in C^{1,1/2}(\partial \Omega \times [0,T])$ and is nonnegative, $g \in W^{2,1}_p(Q_T)$, $u_0 \in W^2_p(\Omega)$, and the compatibility condition
\begin{equation}
    \frac{\partial u_0(x)}{\partial \mathbf{n}}+b(x,0) u_0(x)=g(x,0), \quad x \in \partial \Omega
\end{equation}
is satisfied. It is asserted in the lecture note that the problem admits a unique solution $u \in W^{2,1}_p(Q_T)$, and the following $L^p$ estimate holds:
\begin{equation}
    \|u\|_{W^{2,1}_p(Q_T)} \leq C (\|f\|_{L^p(Q_T)} + \|g\|_{W^{2,1}_p(Q_T)} + \|u_0\|_{W^2_p(\Omega)}),
\end{equation}
where $C$ is a positive constant which only depends on $n,\lambda,\Lambda,\Omega,T,\|b_i\|_{L^\infty(Q_T)},\|c\|_{L^\infty(Q_T)},\|b\|_{C^{1,1/2}(\partial \Omega \times [0,T])}$ and the continuous modulus of $a_{ij}$.

The question is, is $C$ monotonically increasing with respect to $n,\lambda,\Lambda,T,\|b_i\|_{L^\infty(Q_T)}$, etc.? The lecture note I referred omits the proof and I haven't found the proof elsewhere, therefore I have no idea how the constant $C$ depends on those parameters exactly. Can anyone give me some hints or tell me where I can find the proof? Thank you very much.

Comment: Usually it is proved that $C$ stays bounded when $\lambda^{-1}, \Lambda, T, \|b_i\| \dots \le M$. If you define $C(M)$ as the best constant for which the estimate hold with the constraint $M$, this is increasing in $M$.

Comment: This has been posted on (and recieved an Answer) on MSE https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4088765/while-doing-lp-estimates-is-the-constant-c-monotonically-increasing-with-respec

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune Thank you very much! I posted this question because the validity of an outcome in my thesis depends on the monotonicity of $C$, but inspired by your comment, I find it is enough to assure the validity provided $C$ is locally bounded. I will still try to work through the proof and explicitly keep track of the constants involved as it is a great exercise, as is mentioned in the answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4088860/709713.